# Set Cookie if URL parameter exists

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie, using jQuery if the a parameter of a url exists. I'm also performing a check to see if the cookie exists already, if it does I need it to do something and if it doesn't I also need it to do something else.

Here is the code I have

```
$.extend({
 getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
 },
 getUrlVar: function(name){
      return $.getUrlVars()[name];
 }
});

if ($.getUrlVar("fullscreen") != null) {
    var CookieSet = $.cookie('fullscreen', 'yes');
}

if (CookieSet == null) {
   alert('The cookie is not set');
}

if ($.cookie('fullscreen')) {
   alert('the cookie is set');
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on this line (according to the console):

```
var CookieSet = $.cookie('fullscreen', 'yes');
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure the cookie plugin is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't include the jquery cookie plugin.
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Yup, this was the answer. Although now I have another problem. Once I go to the page with the cookie set everything works fine, where I go to another page it does what it should do if it wasnt set. I thought the cookie would have been set and stop that?

Comment: Check if you set the root of your cookie right. Means: If you set a cookie on /foo/bar you can only access it on /foo/bar, unless you set a different root. Try: $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', {path: '/' });. If my answer solved you question please mark it as accepted.